# ViewPager-like animations between three views

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I'm working on a specialized eBook application, where one of the requirements is that it should only display one page of text at a time, with formatting and what not. This proved more challenging than I thought it would, but I've finally managed to do it successfully.

However, now I've run into another problem, namely that the client wants to be able to flip back and forth between pages, ViewPager-style, where the page follows the finger. Now, the number of pages in these books and scriptures aren't predetermined, as I calculate them on-the-fly, each time a chapter is loaded, so that the view automatically handles changes in text size, etc.

I've been looking into various forms of "unlimited ViewPager-flipping", but thus far I haven't been able to find one that seems to work for my purpose.

What I've been considering, and that I hope someone may be able to help me with, is this:

- Three pages, sort of. The one being viewed currently, and one on each side for the flipping.
- When the user flips to a new page, the views will switch places behind the scenes, so that the new page becomes the one in the middle, and loads the next page, while moving the previously viewed page to the opposite end.
- It doesn't technically have to be a ViewPager, if the animation, including the gesture-following, can be achieved in some other way.

I would offer up extra reputation points for this, as I'd really love to solve this quickly, but unfortunately I haven't managed to get a lot of those yet.

Comment: What about simply adding pages to the end of the `ViewPager` as the user scrolls near the end? I know this is a pretty broad suggestion, but if it's something you're looking for I can explain in more detail as an answer.

Comment: @Brian I have already thought about this. However, the user would need to be able to flip both ways, and it would be a terrible memory hog if it kept all the pages loaded. I know there's the 'State' version of the FragmentPagerAdapter, but it still wants me to specify a number of pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to solve your problem with a ViewPager, you need this in your onCreate method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

    // Capture ViewPager page swipes
    ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener ViewPagerListener = new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            super.onPageSelected(position);

            if (fistswitch) {
                mPager.setCurrentItem(1);
                fistswitch = false;
            } else {
                // here you can use the replace method, to switch the
                // fragment behind the scenes
                ArrayList<Fragment> fragmentList = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
                Collections.addAll(fragmentList, new Fr2(), new Fr3(), new Fr4());

                mPagerAdapter.addFragments(fragmentList);
                // after the first switch you can use the the second page
                // continuously as middle
                mPager.setCurrentItem(1);
            }
        }
    };
    mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(ViewPagerListener);
    mPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(fm);
    mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
    ArrayList<Fragment> fragmentList = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
    Collections.addAll(fragmentList, new Fr1(), new Fr2(), new Fr3());

    mPagerAdapter.addFragments(fragmentList);

}
```

The pager adapter class can be a private class in your activity like this:

```
private class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    private List<Fragment> fragmentList = new ArrayList<Fragment>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    public void addFragments(List<Fragment> fragments) {
        fragmentList.clear();
        fragmentList.addAll(fragments);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void replaceFragment(int position, Fragment fr) {
        fragmentList.remove(position);
        fragmentList.add(position, fr);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        if (fragmentList.contains(object)) {
            return POSITION_UNCHANGED;
        }
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int item) {
        if (item >= fragmentList.size()) {
            return null;
        }
        return fragmentList.get(item);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragmentList.size();
    }
}
```

I have not tested the code, but it works for me in a similar case.

Comment: I will check this code later today and get back to you, but it certainly looks promising.

Comment: Quick question, actually, just in case you get to check this before I get a chance to try this out... Won't I get a problem with the `mPager.setCurrentItem(1);` call, since it would jump back to the middle page, which isn't being replaced. Of course, I'll try it out and then attempt to work around it, if that is the case. Just wondering for now.

Comment: I have changed a little bit of the code. Of course you need to replace all fragments. You can check if the user flipped forward or backward with the int position in the method onPageSelected. I've tested it in a App, and it worked. But because of changing the fragment which is visible to the user, it looks not 100% perfect. Maybe working with 4 fragments would solve this problem. Happy testing :)

Comment: I won't be able to fully test this until tomorrow, but obviously, if it works I will mark the answer as accepted. And I'll attempt to work with 4 fragments and see if I can't get that to work as it should. :)

Comment: Okay. That was a really hectic couple of weeks, and I apologize for that. The hectic part is over, however, and I shall get back to you this weekend. :)

Answer (score 0):

There are some good ways to add animation to a ViewPager and alternatively use your own custom views. The first is an open source project called JazzyViewPager by jfeinstein10
This library is really nice and have some animations built in. I've looked at the source in the past and it should be simple to create your own animations if necessary.
The second option is using what's used in JazzyViewPager, namely ViewHelper, which is a class is in the NineOldAndroids animation library by Jake Wharton.

Comment: While I will of course look into the JazzyViewPager, it doesn't sound like the thing I'm after. I'm not trying to add additional animations to a ViewPager, but rather to animate my own views _like_ the ViewPager does, including the way it follows the finger, enabling the user to show both pages at once.

Comment: Do note that JazzyViewPager has a serious memory leak problem. try to make each page have an imageView that shows a large image, and have a lot of pages, and scroll between them. It will take more and more memory till the app crashses... However, it's possible to fix using this link : https://github.com/jfeinstein10/JazzyViewPager/issues/6